# Kendo Chart ".MajorUnit()" value binding from controller side

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-chart

I am unable to bind ".MajorUnit" value from the controller side. I have googled a lot, but could not find the right answer.I have given static value "100" (.MajorUnit(100)) i.e ok. But how can I bind dynamic value returned from controller like .MajorUnit(ViewBag.MyCountValue).

```
@(Html.Kendo().Chart<ExtractorWiseExtractionCount>()
        .Name("userchart")
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 100%; height:150pxpx", id = "ExtDataChart_" + extid })
         //.Title("Extraction Details")
        .Legend(legend => legend
        .Position(ChartLegendPosition.Top)
        )
        .DataSource(ds => ds.Read(read => read.Action("GetExtractionCount", "DashboardStatistics", new { allotId = allotId, extid = extid })))
        .Series(series =>
        {
            series.Line(model => model.ExtCompletedCount).Name("Allocation Wise Extraction");
            series.Line(model => model.IssueReportedCount).Name("Issue Reported");
        })
        .CategoryAxis(axis => axis
        .Categories(model => model.ExtractionDate).Visible(false)
        .Labels(labels => labels.Rotation(-40))
        .Crosshair(c => c.Visible(true))
        )
        .ValueAxis(axis => axis.Numeric()
        .Labels(labels => labels.Format("{0:N0}"))
        .MajorUnit(100)
        )
        .Tooltip(tooltip => tooltip
        .Visible(true)
        .Shared(true)
        .Format("{0:N0}")
        )
     )
```

Comment: Is there any error message? If yes, please append it to your question.

Comment: Please edit your question to include this viable detail. Do not just post it as a comment.